# Does Cersei know about the impending attack on Westeros?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the first season of *Game of Thrones* we saw Robert Baratheon asking Ned Stark to kill Dany before she gathers her troops, so we know that the small council knew about her beforehand.

But after that there has been no mention of her in Westeros. Cersei should be worried about this but there's no hint yet that she, or her council, or her brother Jaime knows about Dany, her dragons and Tyrion and Varys helping her.

My question is how could she not know of such a major plot or if she knows then have there been any such occasions showing it?

I have not read the books only watched the series. In S06E10

> Cersei uses Varys "little birds" to do some amazing things! She could use them again for getting such information?

Comment: No mention? She's mentioned by the small council and Lannisters (mainly Vayres, Littlefinger, Tyrion and Tyrell) every season as a potential threat....

Comment: Then why does she not look worried? Or at least that she start up on some preparations? It looks like that she feels like the war is over now.
(she might not be able to use wildfire now, I think?)

Comment: Based on her actions and attitude, I can only guess either A) she has no idea or B) she knows and doesn't care, since either she thinks the forces at her command can repel the attack (seems unlikely) or she would be just as happy to destroy King's Landing with Wildfire and escape in the chaos or die on the throne.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cersei is likely unaware of how far Daenrys has progressed.

The events of Lady Olenna and Ellaria Sand took place *after* Cersei took the throne. I assume she sat on the throne the same day she burned down the Great Sept, as she has the same clothes on.

Most of the Lords of Westeros has written Daenrys off because the Dothraki would "never" cross the Narrow Sea. Since Varys is no longer being on the Small Council and is actively aiding Daenrys, the flow of information about the events in Essos would likely come to a stop. Qyburn may have the little birds in Kings Landing, but he does not have them all over the world like Varys did.

Comment: I think it's also possible to question if the "little birds" are actually Qyborn's. There are scenes (in the books at least) that show that the "little birds" are still firmly under Varys' control, no matter what Qyborn or Cersei may believe.